# Remove color of element after MouseOver using javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I'm trying to make a star rating system for my Django project using JS and jQuery.
I want to change the color of stars when the mouse is on each star.

I don't want the star color to persist on unhover.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iz1GB_q5txM) tutorial on YouTube.
In this video it seems to work.
JavaScript method preferred

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $(document).ready(function() {

    const starone = document.getElementById('star-first')
    const startwo = document.getElementById('star-second')
    const starthird = document.getElementById('star-third')
    const starfourth = document.getElementById('star-fourth')
    const starfifth = document.getElementById('star-fifth')

    const form = document.querySelector('.rate-form')
    const confirmBox = document.getElementById('confirm-score')
    const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')

    const handleStarSelect = (size) => {
      const children = form.children
      for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (i <= size) {
          children[i].classList.add('checked')
        } else {
          children[i].classList.remove('checked')
        }
      }
    }
    // handleStarSelect(2)

    const handleSelect = (selection) => {
      switch (selection) {
        case 'star-first':
          {
            // starone.classList.add('checked')
            // startwo.classList.remove('checked')
            // starthird.classList.remove('checked')
            // starfourth.classList.remove('checked')
            // starfifth.classList.remove('checked')
            handleStarSelect(1)
            return
          }

        case 'star-second':
          {
            handleStarSelect(2)
            return
          }
        case 'star-third':
          {
            handleStarSelect(3)
            return
          }
        case 'star-fourth':
          {
            handleStarSelect(4)
            return
          }
        case 'star-fifth':
          {
            handleStarSelect(5)
            return
          }

      }

    }

    const arr = [starone, startwo, starthird, starfourth, starfifth]

    arr.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
      handleSelect(event.target.id)
    }))

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.checked {
  color: #f2994a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="user-rating">
  <form action="" method="post" class="rate-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-first"></button>
    <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-second"></button>
    <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-third"></button>
    <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-fourth"></button>
    <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-fifth"></button>
  </form>
  <div id="confirm-score"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you can cut down lots of code by not selecting each element with its classname instead use something like `document.querySelectorAll(".rate-form > button")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the same result with CSS alone. Don't forget to add keyboard focus events.

EDIT: Going over your question again I saw that you didn't want a CSS solution. A CSS solution is often better than a JavaScript solution as some users disable JavaScript for security and CSS can make some things simpler. I'm going to also add a vanilla JavaScript answer for you but I recommend only using JavaScript where absolutely needed.

```css
.stars {
  display: inline flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

.star {
  background-color: initial;
  border: initial;
}

.star:hover,
.star:focus,
.star:hover~.star,
.star:focus~.star {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #f2994a;
}

.star:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #f2994a;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="user-rating">
  <form action="" method="post" class="rate-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="stars">
      <button type="submit" class="star" id="star-fifth"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></button>
      <button type="submit" class="star" id="star-fourth"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></button>
      <button type="submit" class="star" id="star-third"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></button>
      <button type="submit" class="star" id="star-second"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></button>
      <button type="submit" class="star" id="star-first"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="confirm-score"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript solution:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.star').forEach((star) => {
  star.addEventListener('mouseenter', addRating)
  star.addEventListener('focus', addRating)
  star.addEventListener('mouseleave', removeRating)
  star.addEventListener('blur', removeRating)
})

function addRating(event) {
  applyRating(event.target, "add")
}

function removeRating(event) {
  applyRating(event.target, "remove")
}

function applyRating(element, action) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`#${element.id}~.star`).forEach((prevStar) => prevStar.classList[action]('checked'))
  element.classList[action]('checked')
}
```

```css
.stars {
  display: inline flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

.star {
  background-color: initial;
  border: initial;
}

.checked {
  color: #f2994a;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="user-rating">
  <form action="" method="post" class="rate-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="stars">
      <button type="submit" class="star" id="star-fifth"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></button>
      <button type="submit" class="star" id="star-fourth"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></button>
      <button type="submit" class="star" id="star-third"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></button>
      <button type="submit" class="star" id="star-second"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></button>
      <button type="submit" class="star" id="star-first"><i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i></button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="confirm-score"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is impressive (Y)

Answer (score 3):

i just checked your code its working normally but the only problem i saw is that it is selecting next one while hovering in current this is because for loop is running from 0 so `handleStarSelect(0)` means first element

take a look at corrected indexes example

```js
    const starone = document.getElementById('star-first')
    const startwo = document.getElementById('star-second')
    const starthird = document.getElementById('star-third')
    const starfourth = document.getElementById('star-fourth')
    const starfifth = document.getElementById('star-fifth')
    
    const form = document.querySelector('.rate-form')
    const confirmBox = document.getElementById('confirm-score')
    const csrf = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
    
    const handleStarSelect = (size) => {
      const children = form.children
      for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (i <= size) {
          children[i].classList.add('checked')
        } else {
          children[i].classList.remove('checked')
        }
      }
    }
    // handleStarSelect(2)
    
    const handleSelect = (selection) => {
      switch (selection) {
        case 'star-first':
          {
            handleStarSelect(0)
            return
          }
    
        case 'star-second':
          {
            handleStarSelect(1)
            return
          }
        case 'star-third':
          {
            handleStarSelect(2)
            return
          }
        case 'star-fourth':
          {
            handleStarSelect(3)
            return
          }
        case 'star-fifth':
          {
            handleStarSelect(4)
            return
          }
    
      }
    
    }
    
    const arr = [starone, startwo, starthird, starfourth, starfifth]
    
    arr.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
      handleSelect(event.target.id)
    }))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Experiment</title>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        button {background:transparent;border: none;}
        .checked {
            color: #f2994a;
        }
    </style>
    <form action="" method="post" class="rate-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-first"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-second"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-third"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-fourth"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-fifth"></button>
    </form>
</body>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css"> -->
<!-- <script src="./main.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script> -->

</html>
```

i also wanted to suggest my code that i write to perform same behavior if you want to you can use this as well

```js
function manageRating() {
    const btns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".rate-form > button")]

    function reset() {btns.forEach((each) => { each.classList.remove("checked") })}
        
    function rate(number) {
        reset()
        for (let c = 0; c <= number; c++) {
            btns[c].classList.add("checked")
        }
    }

    btns.forEach((each) => {
        each.addEventListener("mouseenter", e => {
            let index = btns.indexOf(e.target)
            rate(index)
        })
    })
    btns[0].parentElement.addEventListener("mouseleave",reset)
}
manageRating()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Experiment</title>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        button {background:transparent;border: none;}
        .checked {
            color: #f2994a;
        }
    </style>
    <form action="" method="post" class="rate-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-first"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-second"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-third"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-fourth"></button>
        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-star fa-lg" id="star-fifth"></button>
    </form>
</body>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css"> -->
<!-- <script src="./main.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script> -->

</html>
```

Comment: This is another good approach. It looks as though you're clearing all buttons on each iteration of a button. Also don't forget to account for keyboard navigation with focus states.

Comment: @ZachJensz since its triggering only when mouseentering and leaving clearing all seems ok and yes i just tried simplified the current code and there is no mention for keyboard navigation although i agree with your comment